# Script not working when migrated from jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.6.2

Tags: jquery, compatibility, jquery-1.3.2, jquery-1.6

This script runs well with jQuery-1.3.2.min.js  but doesn't run with jQuery-1.6.2.min.js .

Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
function moveScroller() {
    var a = function () {
            var b = $(window).scrollTop();
            var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset({
                scroll: false
            }).top;
            var c = $("#scroller");
            if (b > d) {
                c.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: "0px"
                })
            } else {
                if (b <= d) {
                    c.css({
                        position: "relative",
                        top: ""
                    })
                }
            }
        };
    $(window).scroll(a);
    a()
}
$(function () {
    moveScroller();
});
```

Comment: How does it not run? What's the issue?

Comment: $(window).scroll(a);a()  isnt it false ?  should it not be $(window).scroll(a); ?

Comment: offset does not allow `{scroll:false}` what is with that line: `if (b             c.css({position:"relative",top:""})
`

Comment: @Daniel: That code sets `a()` as an event handler for window scroll events, and then calls  `a()`, stand-alone -- presumably to init things.

Comment: should be a 
    ; 
behind it?

Comment: `"should be a ; behind it?"`  It's a very good habit, but JS doesn't require it.

Answer (score 2):

`offset()` [switched to taking coordinates as a parameter with jQuery version 1.4.](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2)

Change:

```
var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset({scroll:false}).top;
```

To:

```
var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
```

We can't help much with the rest of the code without seeing the HTML and CSS that goes with it.

Answer (score 1):

What is:

```
.offset({scroll:false})
```

The offset function does not take a scroll parameter.